# Javascript search and replace sequence of characters that contain square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, escaping

I'm trying to search for '[EN]' in the string 'Nationality [EN] [ESP]', I want to remove this from the string so I'm using a replace method, code examaple below

```
var str = 'Nationality [EN] [ESP]';
var find = "[EN]";
var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
alert(str.replace(regex, ''));
```

Since [EN] is identified as a character set this will output the string 'Nationality [] [ESP]' but I want to remove the square brackets aswell. I thought that I could escape them using \ but it didn't work

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to replace a single instance of it you can just `str = str.replace("[EN] ", "");` otherwise; `var find = "\\[EN\\]";`.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting your regex this way:

`var regex = /\[EN\]/g;`